# issues while download a file from Azure blob storage filename contains hash(#)

Tags: node.js, azure-blob-storage

A file name that contains a hash(#) in the name like (image#12.png) in m Blob storage. Usually, we are generating a SAS token to download the file. Regular files are downloading properly with that SAS token-based URL. But the file name which contains has not been downloaded. Below is the error I am getting in the browser.

```
<Code>AuthenticationFailed</Code>
<Message>Server failed to authenticate the request. Make sure the value of Authorization header is formed correctly including the signature. RequestId:ab30ae48-001e-000f-46da-8969ff000000 Time:2021-08-05T09:15:13.1495259Z</Message>
<AuthenticationErrorDetail>Signature did not match. String to sign used was r 2021-08-05T09:15:11Z 2021-08-08T03:15:11Z /blob/<blob-account-name>/container/image#14.png 2020-08-04 b </AuthenticationErrorDetail>
</Error>
```

Below is my Node.js code to generate the SAS-based URL.

```
let originalname = "image#12.png";  
let FPath = "<BlobPath>";
let urlParts = url.parse(FPath);
var blobName = urlParts.path.split('/').slice(2).join('/');
blobName = decodeURIComponent(blobName);
if (urlParts.hash !== null) {
  blobName += decodeURIComponent(urlParts.hash);
  blobName = blobName.replace(originalname, encodeURIComponent(originalname));
}
const blockBlobClient = containerClient.getBlockBlobClient(blobName);

let expiry = new Date();
expiry.setHours(expiry.getMinutes() + 60);
const sasToken = generateBlobSASQueryParameters(
{
  containerName: containerClient._containerName,
  blobName: blobName,
  startsOn: new Date(),
  expiresOn: expiry,
  permissions: BlobSASPermissions.parse('r')
},
sharedKeyCredential
);
const sasUrl = `${decodeURIComponent(blockBlobClient.url)}?${sasToken}`;
```

That `SasUrl` URL I am accessing through the browser.

Can anyone help me with this?

Comment: Is it possible that the browser does not send the whole URL? The hash `#` token is used to separate the path from the _fragment_, which is used to note the section in the page that should be navigated to when browsing to a URL.